# Difference between $x->{a}{b} and $x->{a}->{b}

Tags: perl

Is there any conceivable difference between

```
$x->{a}{b}
```

and

```
$x->{a}->{b}
```

for any allowed value of `$x->{a}`, in any of the perl versions >= 5.6?

Comment: `perldoc perlref`'s [Using References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References) section point #3 saith, "One more thing here. The arrow is optional between brackets subscripts"

Comment: I was thinking that perhaps a combination of perl versions and/or possible values for `{a}` (e.g. blessed/unblessed/autovivified) may mean a difference, and that I wouldn't be able to know that just from my local 5.10 perldoc output, thus the question :)

Comment: if you are targeting 5.6 but developing on 5.10, you will have some problems.  at the very least, try to check your code using Perl::MinimumVersion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. This is just a syntactic shortcut without any semantic difference.

Proof: the opcodes that are produced upon compilation

```
$ perl -MO=Concise -e'$x->{a}{b}'
b  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{ ->3
a     <2> helem vK/2 ->b
8        <1> rv2hv[t3] sKR/1 ->9
7           <2> helem sKM/DREFHV,2 ->8
5              <1> rv2hv[t2] sKR/1 ->6
4                 <1> rv2sv sKM/DREFHV,1 ->5
3                    <#> gv[*x] s ->4
6              <$> const[PV "a"] s/BARE ->7
9        <$> const[PV "b"] s/BARE ->a
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Concise -e'$x->{a}->{b}'
b  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{ ->3
a     <2> helem vK/2 ->b
8        <1> rv2hv[t3] sKR/1 ->9
7           <2> helem sKM/DREFHV,2 ->8
5              <1> rv2hv[t2] sKR/1 ->6
4                 <1> rv2sv sKM/DREFHV,1 ->5
3                    <#> gv[*x] s ->4
6              <$> const[PV "a"] s/BARE ->7
9        <$> const[PV "b"] s/BARE ->a
-e syntax OK
```

See also [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References), section *Using References*, rule 3.

Answer (score 2):

There are some places where -> didn't become optional until later than 5.6.  I believe these are some:

```
$x->('a'){'b'} # coderef called, returning a reference
({a=>42})[0]{'a'} # reference from a list slice
```

Comment: I didn't think `$x->('a'){'b'}` was valid, and I can't make it work. (Perl 5 v 16)

Comment: I'm not sure where the arrows would have to be in the second example -- can you elaborate?

Comment: @Borodin `perl -E'say sub{+{a=>1,b=>$_[0]}}->("a"){"b"}'` works fine for me, on v5.16.3

Comment: Ah. But `say sub{ +{ a => 1, b => $_[0] } }->('a'){b}` throws a `Bareword "b" not allowed` error. This looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The constructs are identical. Perl allows the `->` between any pair of closing and opening brackets to be omitted.

This works, and prints `OKOK`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = {
  a => {
    b => [
      sub { { c => 'OK' } }
    ]
  }
};

print $data->{a}->{b}->[0]->()->{c};

print $data->{a}{b}[0](){'c'};
```